# php registration, wont work properly.

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a page, where you can register your self into our database, so later on you can use these info to login to the website and access the information.
this is my code for this part:

```
 <?php
        if (isset($_POST['inputFirst']) && isset($_POST['inputLast']) && isset($_POST['inputUsername']) && isset($_POST['inputPassword'])) {
            print "<p>you have registered sucessfully</p>";
            $fname = $_POST['inputFirst'];
            $lname = $_POST['inputLast'];
            $email = $_POST['inputemail'];
            $username = $_POST['inputUsername'];
            $password = $_POST['inputPassword'];
            $tele = "0811111222";
            $add ="testing";
            $loc = "location";

            include 'opendb.php';
            $sql = "insert into Home_User (Fiest_Name,Last_Name,User_ID,Password,Email,Tel,Address,Island,Location) values ('$_POST[inputFirst]','$_POST[inputLast]','$_POST[inputUsername]','$_POST[inputPassword]','$_POST[inputemail]')";
            $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
            print "<p>you have registered sucessfully</p>";
            print "<a href='index.php'>go to login page</a>";
        }           

        else print '<form class="form-horizontal" action="registration.php" method=post>
            <h1> not registered yet</h1>
            <h2>welcome to the registration page</h2>
            please fill in the registration details to create an account. <br/><br/>
            <div class="heading">
                <h4 class="form-heading">Home user registration</h4>
            </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputFirst">First Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="inputFirst" placeholder="E.g. Ashwin">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputLast">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="inputLast" placeholder="E.g. Hegde">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputemail">Email</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="inputemail" placeholder="E.g. hotloving@hotmail.com">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">Username</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="inputUsername" placeholder="E.g. ashwinhegde">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Min. 8 Characters">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputTell">Telephone</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="inputTell" class="bfh-phone" data-format="(ddd) ddd-dddd">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox"> I agree all your <a href="#">Terms of Services</a>
                            </label>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn">Help</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </form>';
        ?>
```

$tele, $add, $loc are other values in the DB where in the form I am not working with them yet.

when I press sign up it doesnt do anything just refreshes the page and it wouldnt give me this:

you have registered sucessfully.

I am not sure what is going wrong, the connection to the database or what. Please help.

Comment: `Fiest_Name` in the `INSERT` statement looks pretty suspect to me...

Comment: You should worry about mysql injection, because your code is full of holes

Comment: But it sounds like you have not turned on error reporting, which is essential for development. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Your code makes use of deprecated functions [`myqsl_*`], plus is highly unmaintainable because you mix DB operations and presentation logic in the same file. Consider moving to an approach that separates such concerns.

Comment: Michael Berkowski, its was suppose to be First_name, however in the DB is also fiest_name table in stead of First_name table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should try using `mysql_real_escape_string` for all POST and GET requests, like

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputemail']);
```

and you are missing the `name` attribute in your input text; it should be

```
<input type="text" id="inputFirst" name="inputFirst" placeholder="E.g. Ashwin">
```

You don't need to print

```
print "<p>you have registered sucessfully</p>"; //don't need before the insertion
```

You should first check whether the insertion was sucessful or not, then you should print it.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

if($result) {
    print "<p>you have registered sucessfully</p>";
    print "<a href='index.php'>go to login page</a>";
} else {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify the names for your inputs, that you are checking in the first if: 'inputFirst', 'inputLast', 'inputUsername', 'inputPassword'.

```
<input type="text" id="inputLast" name="inputLast" placeholder="E.g. Hegde">
<input type="text" id="inputFirst" name="inputFirst" placeholder="E.g. Ashwin">
```

etc

You only have an id there:

```
<input type="text" id="inputFirst" placeholder="E.g. Ashwin">
```